# UL tag list items won't display horizontally

Tags: html, css, list

I have an HTML document that I want to display a simple list horizontally.  There is a plethora of examples on how to do this, but my list will not display horizontally:

HTML:

```
<div id="main_menu">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#1">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#2">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#3">Link 3</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main_menu ul{  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;

}
```

What am I not understanding - why is it not displaying horizontally?

I am testing in Chrome.

Comment: You simply need to tell your main-menu li's to display inline block. do not use the float method as you will need a clearfix for that to really display properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a list display horizontal, either float the `<li>`'s left, or display them `inline` or `inline-block`:

```
#main_menu li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pqrpdd73/)

Answer (score 3):

You either need to float the list items or change their display to inline-block:

**Example 1 - Floats**

```css
#main_menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#3">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Example 2 - Display:inline-block**

```css
#main_menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#3">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use float: left on your li elements to float them horizontally. Please refer to the below example
https://jsfiddle.net/osha90/n2ujqzvo/

```
<div id="main_menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#3">Link 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
#main_menu ul{  
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;

    }
    #main_menu ul li{
      float:left;
      width: 33.33%;
      text-align: center;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
    }
    #main_menu ul li a{
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one option.

**Float:**

```
#main_menu ul li{
    float:left;
}
```

**Flex Box:**

```
#main_menu ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around; /* or other */
}
```

**Display Inline Block:**

```
#main_menu ul {
    display: inline-block;
    justify-content: space-around; /* or other */
}
```